# Admob limits ad serving again, because of an app suspended by google play store

Tags: android, google-play, admob

What if an app suspended and removed by Play Store because of Copy Rights violation? Thats happened to me. One of my App has susspended and removed from Play Store about 5 months ago. 2days after that , Admob limited my account for about 2 months. After that ad serving for other apps back to normal state until today. I didn't do anything when my app get suspended. And now Admob limits my account again because of receiving high ad requests on the suspended app. What i must to do? Removing Ad units of the removed app or what?

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so. If they find that the app shouldn't exist due to copyright infringement, and they find that there are a lot of people using it and in which a lot of ads are shown, they tell in simple terms that you are continuing to violate their policies. So yes, I recommend that you remove the ad units, create others, update the app so that it does not infringe copyright and send it back to the play store (if it does, I don't know)

But the most curious question that comes to me is: what kind of app was it? what did you show copyrighted? In your opinion, has the suspension of the app been corrected?

Comment: Yes, they are right. Use website data legally. But the website actually infringes the copyright and I did not know.

Comment: Not having accepted it as the answer, I wonder, is something unclear or do you want to know more?

Comment: Today I checked my Admob panel and the policy warning was gone.